# JPA avoid child collection initialization if empty

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

Lets say we have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
class Parent {
    @OneToMany(fetchType=FetchType.Lazy,cascade=[CascadeType.ALL])
    val childs: List<Child>
}

@Entity
@Table(name="child")
class Child {
    @ManyToOne(fetchType=FetchType.LAZY)
    val parent: Parent
}
```

I want now avoid, that hibernate does a database fetch the first time i call

`parent.childs.addAll(childs)`

because i KNOW that this collection is empty. Is there a way to tell JPA/Hibernate that it does not need to do the db fetch?

Comment: How do you know that this collection is empty? Is it newly created entity?

Comment: yes, but due to some circumstances i cant add the childs when i creating the parent, so i have to first add the parent and then the childs in a separate step.

Comment: This is an assumption that might be invalidated later when a second mechanism inserts entries when creating `Parent`, also is that SQL query so expensive?

Comment: it seems to be very expensive, he needs for lazy initializing 200 child collections (which can be normal for my operations) up to 10 seconds which is unacceptable. So im searching for optimization approaches and the skipping of this initialization seems to be the best approach here...

Comment: Of course you could also create `Child` directly without adding them to the `childs` collection and saving the `Parent` afterwards if that helps?

Comment: yeah that is the current workaround that i have in mind, but its just a workaround not really a solution....

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around this. Persisting just the child is not a workaround, that's fine. If lazy initialization of a single collection with 200 elements takes 10 seconds, then something with your database setup is wrong. Maybe you are missing an index on the FK column.